# AVL tree, access pointer in struct

Tags: c, avl-tree

```
#define LEFT   1
#define BAL    0
#define RIGHT -1

typedef struct avl {
    int value;
    int bal;
    struct avl *left, *right;
} *AVL;

AVL lower (AVL a){
    while ((a.left != NULL) || (a.right != NULL)) {
        if (a.bal = LEFT){
            AVL lower (a.left);
        } else AVL lower (a.right);
    }
    return (a);
}
```

In this code, I have a problem accessing the `struct` inside my `struct`.
What should I write in this code where I have `a.left`, `a.right`? Thank you all.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "I have a problem"?

Comment: The code won't run, it gets erros compiling, because I'm using something worng but I dont know how I should do it

Comment: Then you should post what the errors say.

Comment: request for member ‘bal’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: It always considers a not a structure or union

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an `AVL`, which is a *pointer* to a `struct avl`.  Thus, to access a field of that structure, you'd need something like `a->left`.